# SpriteKit node fade in issue

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a bunch of SKSpriteNodes which I want to animate in over a scattered duration. The code seems pretty straightforward, but as you can see from [this video](https://croc-share.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/SpriteKit+Stutter.mov), the nodes stutter as they are animating. I'm confident this isn't a genuine performance issue, there aren't that many nodes.

```
actions.append(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2, withRange: 1))
actions.append(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: fadeAnimationDuration))
node.run(SKAction.sequence(actions))
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the nodes might be animating like this?

Comment: For future, adding more tags, such as ios and swift (or whatever you *actually* use) would give the question better visibility. Few people follow such specific tags like sprite-kit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so that was actually a result of me unintentionally calling the same function twice. Actions obviously pile up on nodes, new ones do not replace existing ones.